# Configure karma-firefox-launcher in Angular 15

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular15

Angular 15 comes with fewer configuration files than the previous versions, incl. `karma.conf.js` having been dropped. For running `ng test --browsers=FirefoxHeadless` under Angular 14, I used to configure `karma.conf.js` to `require('karma-firefox-launcher')` plugin.

How should this be done in Angular 15?

- is it ok to copy over the full `karma.conf.js` from the previous Angular 14 project and add set `"architect.test.options.karmaConfig"` in `angular.json` to that `karma.conf.js` file?
- or is there some other way to configure Karma plugins in `angular.json` directly, and would that be better?
- and can Angular 15 still help me by generating an initial `karma.conf.js`?

(motivation: my build server executes `ng test` in a headless container, so for the sake of a simple build container configuration, I prefer `FirefoxHeadless` over the test runner's default browser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Angular 15 you can generate the missing config by doing `ng generate config karma` then modify it to your needs. This also automatically updates the `angular.json` config file for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it manually like you described or you can use karma module to create configuration files from scratch, run: `karma init karma.conf.js` but only headless browser I found was ChromeHeadless (see image).
[image: karma - choose browsers config step]

More in the documentation: http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/intro/configuration.html make sure you follow these steps before: http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/intro/installation.html

After adding a conf file, change angular.json:

```
"test": {
  [...]
  "options": {
    [...]
    "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
    [...]
  }
}
```

After that you can use `ng test` or `npm test` to run the tests.

I think you should not add karma configuration direclty in angular.json (I didn't check if it is even possible)

Comment: picked as "accepted answer", thanks!
(but not 100% confident; Firefox and others should be available, but that again might still need editing config files instead of CLI ?- nothing against config files!)